# O que é Arvore balanceada e quais são as vantagens de utilizá-la?

Tags: lógica, estrutura-de-dados, árvore

Bom a pergunta é basicamente essa, o que é uma árvore balanceada? O que difere ela de uma árvore normal, e quais são as vantagens de utilizá-la?

Uma breve descrição e uma utilização da mesma já está de bastante grado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que é uma árvore balanceada?

Uma Árvore balanceada e uma estrutura onde a profundidade de seu nó esta sempre organizados de forma crescente ou decrescente sendo a raiz sendo o valor central a partir do de sua folhas , ela pode ter um balanceamento estático ou dinâmico.
O balanceamento estático acontece depois que ela recebeu todas as entrada, agora o balanceamento dinâmico acontece com a utilização de algorítimo de Rotação no tempo que a uma nova entrada.

> O que difere ela de uma árvore normal

A diferença é que basicamente uma normal pode ter um lado com muito mais folha e mais profunda tornando assim sua busca mais lenta

> E quais são as vantagens de utilizá-la?

É uma arvore onde a busca se torna mais rápido já que basta uma pegunta para saber qual o caminho que  deve ser seguido.